# Proguard removes overridden methods in abstract class as unused

Tags: java, proguard

Proguard is removing the overridden methods in an abstract class as unused, even though they are used in the parent class. 
Here is a reference implementation showing the behaviour

```
public abstract class Animal {
    Animal() {
        born();
    }

    abstract void born();
}

public abstract class Human extends Animal {
    @Override
    void born() {
        System.out.println("Human is born.");
    }
}
```

The keep attributes are defined as:

```
-keep public class test.Human {
    public *;
}
```

Proguard removes the overridden `born()` methods in Human class as unused, even though it is used from the constructor of Animal class. The resulting mapping file is

```
test.Animal -> test.a:
    void born() -> a
test.Human -> test.Human:
```

This problem does not exist if the class `Human` is not abstract. If the class `Human` is non-abstract, the resulting mapping file is

```
test.Animal -> test.a:
    void born() -> a
test.Human -> test.Human:
    void born() -> a
```

As we can see, the method `born()` is retained in this case.

Is this a bug in proguard? Or is there any optimization setting that can provide the desired behaviour?

I am using proguard with android studio.

Comment: Is there a concrete class that extends Human? If there is not, it could be that it is deducing that `Human.born` can never be executed.

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller There is no concrete class since it is part of the library. The same problem exists if the constructors are replaced by another method which is kept and shows up in the mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem only manifests when these classes are part of a library (and without any concrete implementation within the library), I took the easy way out and added `-dontshrink` to retain (with obfuscation) all the classes and methods.

In most cases; class and method shrinking need not be done when releasing a library.

Still I believe it is a bug in usage graph to ignore the overridden method implementations. I have filed a bug in the proguard bug tracker. https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/574/

Comment: Most likely it will be never fixed because it's not considered a 'bug'...

Answer (score 4):

You configure ProGuard to keep *public* methods, while `born()` is package private. Your configuration should rather be like this.

```
-keep public class test.Human {
    <methods>;
}
```

It will keep all package private (default) methods of Human class.

If you want to keep methods but still allow obfuscation for them, you can use something like this:

```
-keep, allowobfuscation public class test.Human {
    <methods>;
}
```

Comment: the problem here is not about `keeping methods` but about proguard not recognising the overridden method as used and shrinking them leading to an incomplete class file. This only happens when I am creating a library since the problem manifests only in an abstract class. Your suggestion works but is quite like -noshrink which I don't want to use.

Comment: However your suggestion gives me an idea of keeping with obfuscation all the overridden methods of an abstract class in the library which makes sense. What should we use for that?